# I want to reverse the given string like "This is a program" as "sihT si a margorp" using String array in java with out using string functions?

Tags: java

```
    class Reverse_Word
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            String s = "This is a program";
            String str[] = s.split(" ");
            String wrd = new String();
            try{
            for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
            {

                wrd = str[i];
                for(int j=wrd.length();j>=0;j--)
                {
                    String str1[]=wrd.split("//");
                    System.out.println(str1);
                }

            }

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, when I modified the code. Their is no error but getting wrong output like some hashcode
    [Ljava.lang.String;@d70d7a
    [Ljava.lang.String;@b5f53a
    [Ljava.lang.String;@1f6f0bf
    [Ljava.lang.String;@137c60d
    [Ljava.lang.String;@ab853b
    [Ljava.lang.String;@b82368
    [Ljava.lang.String;@11c8a71
    [Ljava.lang.String;@c53dce
    [Ljava.lang.String;@15cda3f
    [Ljava.lang.String;@fc9944
    [Ljava.lang.String;@1b26af3
    [Ljava.lang.String;@8b819f
    [Ljava.lang.String;@eb017e
    [Ljava.lang.String;@aeffdf
    [Ljava.lang.String;@120a47e
    [Ljava.lang.String;@f73c1
    [Ljava.lang.String;@789144
    [Ljava.lang.String;@1893efe

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String str1 = "";// its just a String object
  str1[j] = wrd.split(""); // and you are using it as an array;
```

Changes required :

```
  String str1[];

    str1= wrd.split(""); // I dont know what is your purpose here
```

The code for your answer is

```
 StringBuilder newstring = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            // System.out.println(str[i]);
            wrd = str[i];
            System.out.println("Hi" + str[i]);
           char chars[] = wrd.toCharArray();// converting your string in chars
               for(int k=chars.length-1;k>=0;k--){
                   newstring.append(chars[k]); // appending your characters in reverse order
               } 
               newstring.append(' ');// appending `space` after each word


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println(newstring);// printing your entire reversed string
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course.. 
You have

`String str1 = ""; // str1 is a String and not an array`

and then you do

`str1[j] = wrd.split("");// I am getting error here. because str1 is NOT an array`

Change str1 to an array. `String[] str1 = null;`

Also, `wrd.split("")` does *nothing*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the word to array of characters (an array of strings - each of which is one charatcer) you should use:

```
wrd.split("//");
```

So if `wrd = "This";` it will return the array: `{"T", "h", "i", "s"}`.

Example:

```
String str = "abcd";
String[] arr = str.split("//");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // prints [abcd]
```

Note that since it returns an array of Strings - it will not fit into `str1[j]` (which is an error by itself since a string cannot be accessed like an array) - but I will let you solve this issue by yourself (unless you specifically ask for the complete logic).